# conditional panel function in lattice for multiple y variables

Tags: r, lattice

I have a dataset in which a value (`mean`) can or cannot fall within an interval given by `lower.bound` and `upper.bound`. I would like to plot this using `lattice` and have achieved something really nice, but there are still three things missing, I don't know how to tackle (I am relatively new to `lattice`).

```
df <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=FQh6F12t")

require(lattice)
lattice.options(default.theme = standard.theme(color = FALSE))

head(df)
##    code topic problem mean lower.bound upper.bound consistent
## 7  A04C  coke      MP 99.5       36.45       95.95          0
## 8  A04C  coke      MT 47.5       22.78      100.00          1
## 11 A04C  girl      MP 50.0        4.75        9.75          0
## 12 A04C  girl      MT 99.5       20.00      100.00          1
## 23 A14G  coke      MP 88.5       21.25       66.75          0
## 24 A14G  coke      MT 82.5       48.36      100.00          1    

dotplot(lower.bound + mean + upper.bound ~ code | problem * topic, 
       data = df, pch = c(6, 3, 2), scales = list(x = list(draw = FALSE)),
       as.table = TRUE)
```

This produces:
[image]

The down-arrows/triangles indicate the lower bound, the up arrows/triangles indicate the upper bound and the `+` marks the `mean`. The following things I would like to add to the plot but have no idea how (besides obviously customizing the panel function):

1. **Conditional `pch` based on whether or not a `mean` value is inside the interval.** The variable `consistent` indicates this (0 = outside the interval). `pch` should be `1` for values inside and `3` for values outside the interval. (pch for the lower- and upper bound should remain unchanged)
2. **Marking the interval.** I would like to draw a thicker line between the `lower.bound` and `upper.bound` at each x-axis tick.
3. **Add the proportion of values outside the interval to the panel headers** (e.g., `MP; 58.6%` to the panel in the upper left corner).

For 1 and 2 my problem obviously is, that I don't know how to deal with custom panel function when having multiple y variables (i.e., how to write conditional panel functions based on this). But I couldn't find anything on it.

For 3, the proportion of values outside the interval is given by something like:

```
1 - with(df, tapply(consistent, list(topic, problem), mean))
##          MP     MT
## coke 0.5862 0.1724
## girl 0.8276 0.1724
```

If the answer would furthermore include a nice ordering of levels on the x-axis that would definitely be a plus. The order can change in every panel (i.e., even in panels above each other the same x-axis tick can correspond to a different level of `code`). But this is not important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this isn't real pretty, but it should get the real job (showing you how to get this kind of plot working) done.

The basic idea is to rewrite the formula so that it doesn't have a bunch of names on its LHS (i.e. `lower.bound + mean + upper.bound`). That syntax is equivalent to specifying a `groups=` term, which ends up triggering `panel.superpose()` which is kind of a pain to customize in the way you want.

Instead, I just include `mean` on the LHS, and then use `subscripts` inside of the custom panel function to pick out in each case the matching elements of `upper.bound` and `lower.bound`.

I'm hoping the rest is pretty self explanatory:

```
LABS <- LETTERS[1:4]
with(df,
     dotplot(mean ~ code | problem * topic,
             lb=lower.bound, ub=upper.bound, mpch = c(3,1)[consistent+1],
             ylim = extendrange(c(0,100)),
             panel = function(x, y, lb, ub, mpch, ..., subscripts) {
                 panel.dotplot(x, y, ..., pch=mpch[subscripts])
                 lpoints(x, lb[subscripts], pch=6)
                 lpoints(x, ub[subscripts], pch=2)
                 lsegments(x,lb[subscripts],x,ub[subscripts],col="grey60")
                 ltext(x=x[3], y=95, LABS[panel.number()], col="red",fontface=2)
             },
             scales = list(x = list(draw = FALSE)), as.table = TRUE)
     )
```

[image]

Comment: Man, that is totally awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Henrik -- Glad to be able to help. Once you're comfortable with the `subscripts` argument, **lattice**'s customizable panel functions will really become a **lot** more useful.

Comment: A paper in which we have used the solution presented here has meanwhile [been published](http://journal.frontiersin.org/Journal/10.3389/fpsyg.2014.00316/abstract) (see [Figure 3](http://www.frontiersin.org/files/Articles/74413/fpsyg-05-00316-HTML/image_m/fpsyg-05-00316-g003.jpg)). Thanks for this Josh, you are mentioned in the Acknowledgments.

Comment: @Henrik -- Hey, congratulations, and thanks for alerting me to its publication! It looks very interesting and is quite handsomely laid out -- I'll print it out and take it with me on my next backpacking trip. Cheers.

Comment: I most warn you, it is perhaps not the easiest paper to get into the research on the Psychology of conditionals in human reasoning. But if you are interested and not repelled by the technicality of the question, you can also download the data and R script I used from [my homepage](http://singmann.org/download/publications/data-scripts/2014_singmann_klauer_over.zip).