# assigning colours to plots in lattice according to Set or factor, not groups

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have a lattice plot of experimental data that has 4 datasets (i.e. 4 different subsets in "Config." below), each dataset subdivided according to the config and then also grouped within each test type according to wind direction, "Dir". I am able to set the shape of the points according to the grouping "Dir" across all plots but i cannot then set colours according to "Config" so that for example the first plot has all red points, the second plot has all blue points etc. I am using an xyplot in lattice and the code for the plot is:

```
xyplot(ach[,"F"]~ach[,"Ar_sqrt"] | Config., type=c("p"),ach, groups=Dir, 
   auto.key=list(TRUE, space="bottom", columns=4, padding.text=(8)), 
   Outer=TRUE, allow.multiple=TRUE, as.table=TRUE, scales=list(tick.number=10),
   grid=TRUE, par.settings=simpleTheme(pch=points$shape, cex=1.75, col=1),
   abline=list(c(0,0.2013), col=2, type="l"), layout=c(1,4),  
   panel = function( x,y,...) {
     panel.abline(lm(y~x),col = "black", lwd=1)
     panel.xyplot( x,y,...)
   })
```

I cant attach an image as my rep is les sthan 10, apologies. I have come across different ways of setting colours, etc but they all seem to either use the grouping function.

the data set is available here, (i added columns for pch and col to try and use this but to no avail:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ug9kun9rycsb1fw/AABSXuMs9kEWSgeEAcTYhDkxa

any help or direction to duplicates i didnt find very much appreciated...

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example that is not dependent on your link on Dropbox? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for some hints on how to do that.

Comment: please provide sample of your data... You can use `dput(head(ach,20))`

Comment: You should be able to do this using `panel.number()`. Reproducible examples of its use are given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746597/changing-background-color-in-xyplot/9752056#9752056) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828027/conditional-panel-function-in-lattice-for-multiple-y-variables/16577667#16577667).

Comment: I'm a huge lattice fan, but lattice really only likes to style things by group though you can create custom panel functions for each conditioning level as Josh suggested. This is one of the rare cases which I might suggest ggplot as an alternative. But i must admit i'm still a bit uncertain as to what your final plot should look like.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to use the `pch` and `col` columns it sounds like you've added to your data.frame, use the `subscripts` variable, following the pattern [given in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828027/conditional-panel-function-in-lattice-for-multiple-y-variables/16577667#16577667).

Answer (score 3):

This is best accomplished using `panel.number()`, which gives you access, inside the call to a custom panel function, to the index of the panel being currently plotted.

Here's a simple reproducible example:

```
library(lattice)
lattice.options(default.theme = standard.theme(color = FALSE))
COLORS = c("blue", "gold", "red", "green", "black", "grey")

xyplot(mpg ~ disp | carb, data = mtcars,
       panel = function(x,y,...) { 
           panel.xyplot(x, y, col=COLORS[panel.number()], pch=16, ...)
       })
```

[image]

A couple more involved examples are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746597/changing-background-color-in-xyplot/9752056#9752056) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828027/conditional-panel-function-in-lattice-for-multiple-y-variables/16577667#16577667).

Comment: This example doesn't have a `groups=` parameter. Though it's unclear to me from the OP's description exactly what he's doing with the different groups if he's not coloring points with them but he does have `auto.key` on to put them in the legend.

Comment: @MrFlick To add a grouping factor, just add `groups=cyl`, and remove `pch=16` from the custom panel function.